# vim -u skips some initialization steps

Tags: vim

`vim -u vimrc_file` lets me specify a particular vimrc file to use, however from what I read from `:help initialization` some initialization steps are skipped.

Is there a different option I can use to run vim using a particular vimrc file without skipping those initialization steps? 
or Maybe how can I include those initialization steps that are skipped into the vimrc file?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a different option I can use to run vim using a particular vimrc file without skipping those initialization steps?

Documentation of my VIM 7.1 shows that those initialization steps are only to read from other standard rc files. What IMO is the whole point of the [`-u`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-u) option: only the initialization commands from the user supplied script are read, thus they are guaranteed not to be overridden by standard initialization scripts.

Try the [`-S {file}`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#-S) option to see if it fits your needs better.

Comment: i had to add : in front of every line of my .vimrc (just a bunch of simple set commands) because the file for the -s option will be treated as keypresses, but I guess it will do for now.